# Decide whether the relation is reflexive,symmetric,asymmetric,antisymmetric or transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

R is the relation on the integers such that a is related to b if a+b is odd.

So far I know the relation is transitive because a & c must both be even or odd for the sum of a+b to be odd.

How do I go about the others?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into what symmetric means - if a is related to b, is b related to a? Eg, is a+b odd if b+a is?

And for reflexive: is x+x odd for all x?

Comment: Ah ok so definitely symmetric since addition is commutative

Comment: Yes, and hence you can say something about the asymmetric and antisymmetric hypotheses as well I hope! :)

Answer (score 0):

Addition is commutative so $a+b=b+a$. Clearly, if one of these is odd, so is the other and this gives us the symmetric property.
As for the reflexive property, $a+a=2a$ which is clearly not odd if $a$ is an integer.